# AWS CloudFormation - Load JSON map as template parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a JSON object that looks like this, with each top-level key representing an AWS account ID:

```
{
   "123456789012": { 
      "key1": "val1",
      "key2": "val2"
   },
   "123456789013": { 
      "key1": "val1",
      "key2": "val2"
   },
   .
   .
   .
}
```

I would like to store that JSON in Systems Manager Parameter Store and then load that into my CloudFormation parameters so that I can reference it later by using the `AWS::AccountId` pseudo param as the key in my JSON. I was hoping to be able to use `FindInMap` for this or something similar. My ultimate goal is to be able to deploy StackSets across multiple accounts and to reference that JSON for each account and load dynamic parameters.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you have to store that in systems manager? Sounds like you are complicating things needlessly

Comment: @Paolo I don't need to, looking to see if there's another way of doing it

Comment: Just embed the key value pairs in the template with a mapping

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that with either a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) or a [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) that you have to develop in a form of a lambda function.